# Flutter - How to use multiple ChangeNotifierProvider's

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart

I'm new in flutter and I'm trying to figure out how I can use multiple ChangeNotifierProvider's in the `main.dart` class

I have been struggling with this for hours and I just cannot seem to get this to work.

The multiple ChangeNotifierProvider's is  used for the Auth Screen as well as the Theme Changer.

```
void main() async {
  var delegate = await LocalizationDelegate.create(
      fallbackLocale: 'en_US', supportedLocales: ['en_US', 'sv']);

  runApp(LocalizedApp(delegate, MyApp()));
}
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final theme = Provider.of<ThemeChanger>(context);
    var localizationDelegate = LocalizedApp.of(context).delegate;

    FlutterStatusbarcolor.setStatusBarWhiteForeground(false);

    return MultiProvider(
      providers: [
        ChangeNotifierProvider.value(
          value: Auth(),
        ),

        ChangeNotifierProvider<ThemeChanger>(
          create: (_) => ThemeChanger(CustomThemes.lightTheme.copyWith(
              textTheme:
                  CustomThemes.textTheme(CustomThemes.lightTheme.textTheme))),

          child: MaterialAppWithTheme(),
        )
      ],

      child: Consumer<Auth>(
        builder: (ctx, auth, _) => MaterialApp(
          title: translate('appbar.title_app'),
          localizationsDelegates: [
            GlobalMaterialLocalizations.delegate,
            GlobalWidgetsLocalizations.delegate,
            localizationDelegate
          ],
          supportedLocales: localizationDelegate.supportedLocales,
          locale: localizationDelegate.currentLocale,
          theme: theme.getTheme(),
          color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
          home: auth.isAuth ? MdDrawer(title: AppStrings.appTitle) : AuthenticationScreen(),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MaterialAppWithTheme extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final theme = Provider.of<ThemeChanger>(context);

    return MaterialApp(
      title: AppStrings.appTitle,
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      theme: theme.getTheme(),
      color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
      home: MdDrawer(title: AppStrings.appTitle),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: What is the problem or error here?

Comment: I don't get an error in VS Code but in the app there is a red screen with yellow text that says >>> `Error: Could not find the correct Provider<ThemeChanger> above this MyApp widget

This is likely happens becouse you used a BuildContext that does not include the provider of your choice.`

Comment: Have you put a Provider widget on top of your widget tree?

Comment: I don't really understand what you mean.

All I have above the `MyApp Class` is the main `main() function`

I have updated the code above

Answer (score 0):

You can use a provider of an object in a widget only if the widget is wrapped by the provider or is a child of the widget that is wrapped by that provider. This is what means by placing your provider on top of your widget tree.

Here you have a used the MultiProvider inside the widget and `final theme = Provider.of<ThemeChanger>(context);` is in the part of the widget that isn't wrapped by the provider.

So instead of creating a theme variable directly use
`theme: Provider.of<ThemeChanger>(context).getTheme();`